# Apparently missing scipy function

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

When I run the script below, which is taken from scipy documentation, I get the
error ‘Attribute Error: module 'scipy.integrate' has no attribute 'cumulative_trapezoid'
When I run dir (integrate) there is no mention in the list of the functions 'cumulative_trapezoid'

```
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, num=20)
y = x
y_int = integrate.cumulative_trapezoid(y, x, initial=0)
plt.plot(x, y_int, 'ro', x, y[0] + 0.5 * x**2, 'b-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you verify what version of scipy you are using, and add that here?

Answer (score 0):

`cumulative_trapezoid` was added to SciPy in version 1.6.  You can check which version you have with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  In older versions of SciPy, the function is called `cumtrapz`.